# Resolving Typescript compiler messages for the runtime Javascript attributes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a piece of code like below:

```
<div class="authentication-validation-message-container">
  <ng-container *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
    <div class="validation-error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required.</div>
    <div class="validation-error-message" *ngIf="email.errors.email">Email is not in the valid format. Please use a valid
      email.
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="pwd.invalid && (pwd.dirty || pwd.touched)">
    <div class="validation-error-message" *ngIf="pwd.errors.required">Password is required.</div>
  </ng-container>
  <div class="validation-error-message" *ngIf="!verdict">{{errorMessage}}</div>
</div>
```

If you are using Angular, you can check if the inputs have invalid data in them by using a code like `email.errors.required`. However, `.required`, `.email`, etc. all come during the run time execution of JS, so there are not known during the compile-time by TypeScript.

When I look at the IDE (using Jetbrains Rider, btw), I am seeing these compile time warnings that I'd like to resolve them in the TypeScript idiomatic way:

[image]

I have tried `(email.errors as any).required` but the warnings won't go away. I believe `as` is now the recommended way of casting instead of `(<any> email.errors).required`. Well, neither of them worked anyway. So what would your recommendation be without me going to the component (Angular concept) and modify them, such as exposing these errors messages thru properties, etc.

**Edit:**

These are the warning messages:

[image]

Comment: what does the warning tell?

Comment: @messerbill Check out the new edit now.

Comment: does the warning disappear using this notation: `*ngIf="email["errors"]["required"]`?

Comment: Include text information as text, not images.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/126#issuecomment-317155658

Comment: One suggestion in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/152) is to use the safe navigation operator: `email?.errors.required`.

Comment: i think you either have to define that type or use the notation i posted above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is the type that is expected to be there. The `ngIf` constructs expects to have an expression with `boolean` result, but as of the actual state, your code isn't ensuring that requirement. To make the warnings dissapear you should navigate safely using the `'?'` operator or cast the expression to `boolean` type.

For instance you can do:

```
<div class="validation-error-message" *ngIf="email?.errors.required">Email is required.</div>
<div class="validation-error-message" *ngIf="email?.errors.email">Email is not in the valid format. Please use a valid
```

Comment: This was the issue and you answered correctly. Interesting, though. The error messages are totally misleading then.